# HTML/CSS hover affecting parent element +Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am testing my navigation bar for a project and I am using basic Html/css 
and i have added Jquery so that the hover effect could affect the parent element.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav-level-2").hover(
  function () {
     $("li>a").css("background", "white");
  }
);
   $(".nav-level-2").mouseleave(
    function () {
     $("li>a").css("background", "none");
  });
  });
```

```css
.main-nav {
    background: #000;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    cursor: default;
}

.main-nav .inner{
    height: 100%;
}

.main-nav>.inner{
    text-align: justify;
}

.nav-links-container {
    position: static;
    /* background: red; */
    height: 100%;
    
}

.nav-links{
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
     /*background-color: green; */
}

li {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* background: blue; */
}

li>a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 9px 9px;
    margin: 0 -3px;
}
li>a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color:#000;    
}

.nav-level-2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    background: red;
    text-align: left;

}

.nav-level-2-container {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    -ms-flex: 0px 1px auto;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0px 1px auto;
    flex: 0px 1px auto;
}

li>a:hover + .nav-level-2{
    display: block;
  
} 

.nav-level-2:hover {
  display:block;
  
}


.row{
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;    
}

.list-container {
    padding: 0px;
}

.col-lg-2{
    flex-basis: 16.666666667%;
    max-width: 16.666666667%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 5px;
    
}

.main-nav>.inner .nav-level-2 .nav-level-2-container .heading {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="main-nav">
<div class="inner max-girdle-width">
                        <div class="nav-links-container">
                          <ul class="nav-links">
                            <li class="nav-whats-new"> <a class="nav-level-1" href="#">What's New</a>
  <div class="nav-level-2">
                                <div class="nav-level-2-container row max-girdle-width">
                                   <div class="list-container shop col-lg-2">
                                                   <h3 class="heading"> Shop by</h3> 
                                                    
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </nav>
```

What I am trying to achieve is when I hover over the red block,I am trying to make parent element ('What's New') to show with color #000 and background white;

[SEE THIS IMAGE <--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRZ46.png)

I know that when i hover 'What's New' it does change color to white, but when I hover over redblock for navigation, the background disappears with 'What's New' disappearing with black background.

Answer (score 2):

No need for JavaScript to do what you want.  I think this is what you are looking for?  Basically, I am using the `:hover` on the parent div to change the child element's background and colour.

```
.nav-whats-new:hover a {
   background:white;
   color:black;
}
```

Example:

```css
.main-nav {
    background: #000;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    cursor: default;
}

.nav-whats-new:hover a {
   background:white;
   color:black;
}

.main-nav .inner{
    height: 100%;
}

.main-nav>.inner{
    text-align: justify;
}

.nav-links-container {
    position: static;
    /* background: red; */
    height: 100%;
    
}

.nav-links{
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
     /*background-color: green; */
}

li {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* background: blue; */
}

li>a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 9px 9px;
    margin: 0 -3px;
}
li>a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color:#000;    
}

.nav-level-2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    background: red;
    text-align: left;

}

.nav-level-2-container {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    -ms-flex: 0px 1px auto;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0px 1px auto;
    flex: 0px 1px auto;
}

li>a:hover + .nav-level-2{
    display: block;
  
} 

.nav-level-2:hover {
  display:block;
  
}


.row{
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;    
}

.list-container {
    padding: 0px;
}

.col-lg-2{
    flex-basis: 16.666666667%;
    max-width: 16.666666667%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 5px;
    
}

.main-nav>.inner .nav-level-2 .nav-level-2-container .heading {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="main-nav">
  <div class="inner max-girdle-width">
    <div class="nav-links-container">
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="nav-whats-new"> <a class="nav-level-1" href="#">What's New</a>
          <div class="nav-level-2">
            <div class="nav-level-2-container row max-girdle-width">
              <div class="list-container shop col-lg-2">
                <h3 class="heading"> Shop by</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: omg. i totally just missed that. Genius over here. Thank you so much. I am improving my html/css. I am visual designer but i want to implement my design with codes. So i have been practicing. Any advice on fast ways to improve html/css??????

Comment: +1 here for removing the jquery that really isn't needed (you can also remove the `script` tag in your snippet :) )

Comment: +echang - I learned by "doing", so what you're doing is probably the best I could suggest.  Try things, ask questions, and learn.  :)  +Dekel thanks for the suggestion, I have updated.

Comment: You can also add text-decoration: none; to remove the line under what's new

Answer (score 0):

See the edited jQuery. It's what I changed. Change background none to transparent and add the color css styles.

Is this what you wanted?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav-level-2").hover(
       function () {
         $("li>a").css("background", "white");
         $("li>a").css("color", "black");
       }
    );
    $(".nav-level-2").mouseleave(
       function () {
         $("li>a").css("background", "transparent");
         $("li>a").css("color", "white");
      }
    );
});
```

```css
.main-nav {
    background: #000;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    cursor: default;
}

.main-nav .inner{
    height: 100%;
}

.main-nav>.inner{
    text-align: justify;
}

.nav-links-container {
    position: static;
    /* background: red; */
    height: 100%;
    
}

.nav-links{
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
     /*background-color: green; */
}

li {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* background: blue; */
}

li>a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 9px 9px;
    margin: 0 -3px;
}
li>a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color:#000;    
}

.nav-level-2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    background: red;
    text-align: left;

}

.nav-level-2-container {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    -ms-flex: 0px 1px auto;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0px 1px auto;
    flex: 0px 1px auto;
}

li>a:hover + .nav-level-2{
    display: block;
  
} 

.nav-level-2:hover {
  display:block;
  
}


.row{
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;    
}

.list-container {
    padding: 0px;
}

.col-lg-2{
    flex-basis: 16.666666667%;
    max-width: 16.666666667%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 5px;
    
}

.main-nav>.inner .nav-level-2 .nav-level-2-container .heading {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="main-nav">
<div class="inner max-girdle-width">
                        <div class="nav-links-container">
                          <ul class="nav-links">
                            <li class="nav-whats-new"> <a class="nav-level-1" href="#">What's New</a>
  <div class="nav-level-2">
                                <div class="nav-level-2-container row max-girdle-width">
                                   <div class="list-container shop col-lg-2">
                                                   <h3 class="heading"> Shop by</h3> 
                                                    
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </nav>
```